# How do I call a secured Google Apps Script web app endpoint?

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I want to make a POST request to my Google Apps Script Web App, but I don't know what format google wants me to send my credentials in. I have restricted access to the API to anyone in my gmail domain. The script that is making the POST request is written in Python and running automatically on a server, no user input.

Even a link to a page of documentation that addresses this issue would be great. I searched but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until a few months ago there was no authenticated way to do server to webapp calls. The webapp had to run as the author with anonymous access. 
Recently a new service was released called the Execution API. Which allows someone to execute a script using a simple REST call.

Overview of the service:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/

Python quickstart:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/target-script